# How can I ignore first line and read and store values from second line of text file in csh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh

I have a text file in which data is stored in this format-

```
Sample|Name|Date|Value1|Value2|Value3
Example|shell|20210825|1400.67|1456.98|1234.56
```

Now I want to print the values only from this text file to another text file using an automated script like this-

```
Value 1 is: 1400.67
Value 2 is: 1456.98
Value 3 is: 1234.56
```

I have tried following bash script but bash script, but I only require shell script as it is compulsion to use shell script.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 OLDIFS=$IFS
 IFS="|"

 filename=Sample.txt

 {

 read 
 while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6

 do

 echo "Value 1 is: [$f4]
 Value 2 is: [$f5]
 Value 3 is: [$f6]
 " > output.txt

 done
 } < ${filename}
 IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If anyone has any work around in this please help! PS Thanks in advance;)

Comment: You have _csh_  in the tags and the titl of your question, the script has a `bash` #! line, and the code itself is neither valid bash nor csh. Please make up your mind first what language you are going to use.

Comment: If you want to stick with bash or with POSIX shell (clarify which you want), paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), before posting here.

Comment: @user1934428 I am new to this and don't know scripting. Please read what have I written, and the script is running fine at my end.

Comment: I see that you have updated it. Would you now also remove the references to _csh_? There is nothing in the question related to csh. Also it is not clear from your question what you are missing. At the first glance, it looks correct, and you say yourself that it's running fine.

Comment: The script is correct. I want the bash script converted in the csh script as it is compulsion to work in csh. But csh read command and IFS is not working hence I am stuck as main logic of script was based on these two commands.

Comment: People are still seriously programming in csh???? Some dinosaurs never get extinct .....

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution

```
#!/bin/csh

set filename = "Sample.txt"
echo > output.txt

foreach line ( "`sed '1d' $filename`" )
   set argv = ($line:as/|/ /)
   echo "Value 1 is: [$4]" >> output.txt
   echo "Value 2 is: [$5]" >> output.txt
   echo "Value 3 is: [$6]" >> output.txt
   echo >> output.txt
end
```

Comment: Thanks Davide Madrisan, but actually I need csh script, the bash script I have provided in the question is working fine. But I need to convert it into csh script. I have just provided that bash script for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. I've replaced the bash script with a csh one.